# how to set image for three js cube

Tags: three.js

Am new to three js. Am trying to set background image and want to change front face with image also.

Gone through more example from net, but am not getting idea.

Please tell me with simple examples.

Here is the cube [link](http://threejs.org/examples/#canvas_geometry_cube)

Comment: The link goes to the Threejs website demo, have you got something of your own like a jsfiddle/codepen ? Would be great to start explaining from what you have already got so far :)

Comment: You should just look at the [three.js examples](http://threejs.org/examples). All you need is there. If you have more specific problems you should explain more in detail what you want help with.

Answer (score 2):

You just can add your texture to your box:

```
var dice = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.BoxGeometry( 50, 50, 50),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
         map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('texture.png')
      }) 
    );
dice.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
scene.add( dice );
```

And for background you can use `SphereGeometry()` geometry and change the background.